# What is the meaning of "the moment in time of closest distance" between two moving objects?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime

Two objects $A$ and $B$ are moving along skew lines. Is there a reasonable definition of **the moment in time where the objects have minimal distance from each other**?

In a Newtonian world with global time I can calculate the distance of the objects at every moment in time and find a minimum. However the number I get is a highly theoretical object to which no element of physical "reality" will correspond. So I am thinking of an experiment which provides me with that time.

For example: At every moment in time object $A$ sends out small probing objects in all directions. The objects move at constant speed and carry a clock with them. After a while some of them (those sent into the right direction) will arrive at $B$ and punch the clock. Then, from traveling time and speed, they can derive the distance they traveled. I then pick the object with minimal travel distance and check their log-books for starting time.

However, there are at least two issues with this: First: To which time will I assign the notion of distance? The starting time? And with which right? Second, even worse: The distance and time will depend on the speed of the objects - although one might get "good" results taking the limit of the speed to infinity.

That said: What will I see in a real world experiment? With subluminal speeds this notion of distance will depend on the chosen speed. Using light will (apart from the difficulty that I cannot carry along a physical clock) yield to a zero time difference measured on the traveling clock. And again: To which moment in time does this distance belong? During the time the objects travel both objects are moving and changing their distance.

So: Is there a reasonable definition of **the moment in time where the objects have a minimal distance from each other**? It looks like yes, at least in [Transformation of angles in special relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13638/transformation-of-angles-in-special-relativity) the poster and the commenters take it as granted.

However, I am no longer sure what they mean.

**Making things more precise:**

I am looking for a *frame independent* notion of "distance".

I am looking for an *experiment* by which I could determine this "distance". So I am not looking for
"Let us assume theory XYZ and then calculate this-and-that". I am looking for "do experimental
procedure ABC and then read 'distance' as value on instrument number 42".

My problem is: When this notion of "distance" is an element of physical reality (not requiring any
ideology on space, time or space-time) then I should be able to define an experiment whose outcome
is this "distance" or rather the moment in time where a reasonable notion of distance is minimal.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a reasonable definition of the moment in time where the objects have a minimal distance from each other?

There cannot be any in general. The minimal distance is given by  two specific events A and B on objects worldlines, that need to be simultaneous. The relativity of simultaneity then dictates, that there are inertial observers that disagree whether the events A and B are simultaneous and these will then necessarily pick different pair of events as those determining closest distance.

In the homework you linked to, there are three reference frames mentioned. If USS Enterprise sends the shuttle when the USS Voyager is closest according to itself (at time $0$), then the two events will have coordinates $A=(0,0,0,0)$ and $B=(0,0,d,0)$. Because to get to other two reference frames we are boosting only in $x$ direction, the time coordinate of both events will remain $0$ and the two events will remain simultaneous. So in the example, it makes sense to say "At the exact moment the two space ships are closest together (at a distance d)", because the boosts considered spoil neither simultaneity, nor the distance d. One could not correctly say this if he included another reference frame boosted in, say, y direction.

Comment: That is what I suspected. My problem (still) is that of semantics with the homework text. Why would one possibly speak of "distance" (in my understanding used in a context supposed to reflect an element of physical 'reality') when in fact what is meant is an arbitrary concept which only makes sense if you added further assumptions in the mind of the person posing the task ("if he included another reference frame"). Mind reading is no physical concept ;-). Similarly textbooks often use "moving" which, in my understanding, is a non-concept without always explicitly adding the reference frame.

Comment: @Nobody-Knows-I-am-a-Dog Because in the context of the homework it should be clear what one means. Insisting on more complicated terminology should be justified by significant reduce in misinterpretation. But if your listeners usually understands you, there is no point in complicating the language. My advice is, do not dwell on terminology of others so much, rather try to understand them from the context. If you are still unsure about their meaning, then just ask for clarification. Otherwise you may end up becoming a mathematician (joke).

Comment: LOL. ROFL. Why? Because by training I am a PhD-level mathematician and my (only) problems with physics are of exactly this nature (that physicists drop 95% of the important details claiming they "should be clear"). Things do not get easier by dropping details, at least from my perspective - I rather enjoy the possibility of explaining things clearly with all the (essential) details. Thank you for you help on this one and I particularly enjoyed the joke :-)

Comment: @Nobody-Knows-I-am-a-Dog Yes, there is great disagreement between mathematicians and physicists about what "essential" detail means. But physicist model real world. The real world is primary, the mathematical model is just a description. So they build their intuition about how real world behaves. Then, when doing computation, they already know a lot about what kind of properties should the result have only from the physical situation and they use them to get to the result. (cont.)

Comment: ... Mathematicians on the other hand, build intuition about theories. Then they need a lot of mathematical details  to know what to expect from the result on top of the physical description, because they do not know how to deduce properties from physics alone and they need more detailed description of the theory, because without this details, the theory is unpredictable.

Comment: if this makes sense:)

Comment: I see our point. My problem is with "deduce properties from physics alone". (I think) we cannot deduce anything in physics. "Deduction" makes sense only in formal (math) theories. Physics does not get punished for their sloppiness when/since their "self proclaimed deductions" do not violate observation. World would be easier (for me) if physics clearly indicated (all) proper details and then left the rest to math (where alone deduction is defined).

Comment: @Nobody-Knows-I-am-a-Dog Let me say it this way - when you are driving a car and your navigator tells you "turn right", do you also complain he did not specify in which POW he is speaking? Most probably not, as you understand him, And you most probably would quickly get annoyed if he would say "turn right from the point of view given by the direction of our motion" at every turn....

Comment: ...But wait, you can also complain he did not stated in which reference frame our motion is defined, so he should say "turn right from the point of view given by the direction of our motion with respect to the road". Well, by the time he finally states clearly how you should turn, you might completely miss it! As a driver, isn't it better in the long run to learn to understand what "turn right" means in that given situation? Similarly, as a physicist, isnt it better in a long run to learn to certain implicit assumptions that recur often?

Comment: I admit to the sin of "wanting to understand" and to not using navigators, since I usually turn too early or too late :-). I find it negligent when in an area of physics where you make it a core issue that simultaneity is an observer artifact and spatial and temporal distances are frame dependent - the observer and frame is not stated. This makes it difficult for the uninitiated to enter this field of magic ;-).

Answer (score 1):

By "distance" I presume you mean spatial distance only. This is a frame dependent concept, so clearly there is no unique answer to your question.

However, if by "distance" you mean distance in spacetime according to the Minkowski metric then that's another story. The worldline of A is described by a line $A=A(\tau)$ in 4-space, and that of B by another worldline $B=B(\tau')$. If both A and B are inertial then there will be events $A_0$ and $B_0$ where the distance $||A(\lambda)-B(\lambda)||$ is minimal (provided the lines are not "parallel"... this is complicated by the indefiniteness of the metric, I think).

Comment: I am in search of a frame independent concept. Did you mean to write $||A(\lambda)-B(\lambda^\prime)||$? Minimizing over two parameters? Otherwise we again would get dependence of distance of the (unphysical) parametrization. Would we then have an experiment yielding this "distance"?

Comment: I think it doesn't matter what parameterizations you use for the two lines, you're finding the minimum spacetime interval between the lines. This is a *spacetime* interval, not a spatial one, so how the components come out as "time" and "spatial distance" will be coordinate dependent, but the quantity $ds^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2 - dt^2$ is invariant.

Comment: We are minimizing a distance between two 1-dimensional manifolds, correct? Then this gives us one parameter per 1-dim manifold. The parameter $\lambda$ for $A$ and $\mu$ for $B$ both must be varied and we minimize $d(A(\lambda), B(\mu))$. If we minimize $d(A(\lambda), B(\lambda))$ as you suggested, then a re-parametrization of $B$ by shifting with +2 yields the minimization of $d(A(\lambda), B(\lambda + 2))$ and this is a completely different minimum then. Or did I misunderstand a crucial point in your comment?

Comment: Yes, you're right, there should be two different parameters.